# Generate HTML file from Gravity Form Submission

Tags: php, html, gravity-forms-plugin

How do I generate an html file (with specific styling) from a Gravity Form submission using PHP? Right now, I'm using Gravity Form with Gravity PDF to generate PDFs, but I also need these pdfs to be generated as html files. I was told that I could use a gf hook called gform_notification. Here is what I have so far:

```
add_filter( 'gform_notification_30', 'add_attachment_html', 10, 3 ); //target form id 2, change to your form id
function write_html($filename, $entry){
$filename = fopen( 'file_'.'rand(0, 999999)'.'.html', "w");
$text = $entry;
$path = '/public_html/wp-content/uploads/HTML/';
fwrite($path.$filename, $text);
fclose($filename);  }

function add_attachment_html( $notification, $form, $entry ) {
//There is no concept of user notifications anymore, so we will need to target notifications based on other criteria,
//such as name or subject
if( $notification['name'] == 'HTML' ) {
    //get upload root for WordPress
    $upload = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_path = $upload['basedir'];

    //add file, use full path , example -- $attachment = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wpdev\\wp-content\\uploads\\test.txt"
    $attachment = $upload_path . $filename;

    GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): file to be attached: ' . $attachment );

    if ( file_exists( $attachment ) ) {
        $notification['attachments']   = rgar( $notification, 'attachments', array() );
        $notification['attachments'][] = $attachment;
        GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): file added to attachments list: ' . print_r( $notification['attachments'], 1 ) );
    } else {
        GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): not attaching; file does not exist.' );
    }
}
//return altered notification object
return $notification;
}
```

I'm brand new to coding so please bear with me. My biggest issue is generating the new HTML file. I think I can figure out how to attach it to the notification email (function add_attachment_html) once I get that part done.

Comment: Please see [ask]. No one here is going to write or design your code. Do some research to figure out your problem space and then give it a try.

Comment: Sorry, I was working on the code and forgot to post it. I will edit my response to include that. My bad.